# Keeping Hibernate session open all the time

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm building a reverse-proxy server that will authorize and pass-through http requests to some internal API.

I am authorizing incoming requests based on entries in `Postgres` DB.

Performance in this project is priority - the reverse-proxy server shouldn't add a lot to response times.

**To the point:**
I am using `Hibernate` to query the DB. `DB is read-only.` I'm openning Hibernate session during init in Spring Configuration:

```
@Bean
public Session session()
{
    LOG.info("Opening Hibernate session...");
    try
    {
        return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
    catch (final HibernateException ex)
    {
        LOG.error("HibernateException while opening Hibernate session.", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I then inject Session into DAO layer and I use it in read method:

```
@Repository
public class MappingDAOHibernate implements IMappingDAO
{
    @Autowired //in fact this is autowired using constructor
    private final Session session;

    .....

    //read method
    @Override
    public MappingDto getMapping() throws SQLException
    {
        this.session.beginTransaction();
        return (MappingDto)this.session.createCriteria(MappingDto.class)
    }
```

As you can see - I am not closing/opening Session on every DAO call. I just open it at the App init and I keep it open for the whole time.
Reasons are:
1. that was the quickest and simplest implementation
2. I would like to avoid performance overhead with opening/closing session

**Question:**
1. Is it acceptable to keep Hibernate Session open all the time? Especially if DB is read-only?

Comment: Each extra session eats out some of your ram, read-only makes it safe to use but it is extremely memory inefficient and generally a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to avoid performance overhead with opening/closing session

Have you benchmarked this? Most of the overhead of creating a session can be saved by using connection pooling. I suggest measuring the overhead of creating a session before prematurely optimizing it.

If you decide to try keeping the session open long-term, I suggest benchmarking the memory usage, too. Hibernate has a session cache of the entities, which could balloon over time.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider not only performance. Estimate the **maximum number of your concurrent sessions** - is it comparable with the connection pool size (i.e. can the database support this number of connections)?

Also keep in mind that relatively **small number of "hanging" sessions** can exhaust your connection pool and effectively **block the whole application**.